# download doc file on android from server

Tags: java, android, sockets

hi i have a word document on server which i want to download it from android.i am using the following code

```
               URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
               URLConnection conexion =  url.openConnection();
               conexion.setDoOutput(true);
               conexion.setConnectTimeout(60000);

               conexion.connect();

               int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
               Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile);

               InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(conexion.getInputStream());
               OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + 
                        "/abcd.doc");

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();`
```

when i try this code with a sample flickr link(http://farm1.static.flickr.com/114/298125983_0e4bf66782_b.jpg) it works but when i try my server url it doesnt connect.The file gets downloaded from browser though.Also can sombody tell me what is the difference between two methods  openConnection() and connect() ?

Update:

It also works fine with our localhost but not on the server. In logcat I see, Request time failed: Address family not supported. Something need to be set for Doc files?

Answer (score 0):

URL.openConnection(); prepares connection to be made Connect is the start of conection i think sorry if i'm wrong.

JAVADOC SAYS THESE

connect() Opens a connection to the resource. This method will not reconnect to a resource after the initial connection has been closed.

URL.openConnection() Opens a connection to the remote resource specified by this URL. This connection allows bidirectional data transfer.

hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set the content-type for word documents:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-word";
```

But there are variations depending on the version.